# problem in installing ubuntu

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu-10.04, installation, resolution

I have a hp pavilion dv6000 notebook. I installed windows 7 in it. It worked fine for six months. Now there is some problem in the graphic card or something. My screen olution is set to something 600 x 400(these are not exact). The default monitor is on. It is not allowing me to change the screen resolution. I thought it's a driver problem, so I tried all the possible nvidea drivers but nothing worked. The images are very big on screen and scrren is cut. I decided to install ubuntu on that . I created a bootable pen drive and tried to install it. But it's not allowing me to install. The laptop is continuously restarting. Can anybody help me in this?

Give sollution for any problem, changing the screen resolution, or how to off default monitor or how to install ubuntu.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds dead to me.

Comment: means? The laptop won't work anymore?? Don't say this. I have just joined a course where laptop is compulsory and I don't have resource to purchase another one. Any ideas guys?

Comment: Hardware has a limited life. Some generally lasts longer than others, but it all breaks down sometime.

Comment: You need to explain better before anyone can help you. What does "not allowing me to install" mean exactly?  I have Ubuntu on a DV6000 and have had few problems.

Comment: I have mentioned. The laptop is continuously restarting.

Answer (score 1):

Does Ubuntu work from Live CD, with a proper resolution?
If it does, and only refuses to install (which happens sometimes even on perfectly working machines), you can try some another Linux distribution, [Linux Mint](http://www.linuxmint.com/download.php) for instance.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. I will try a live cd or other versions of linux. Hope it will work.

Comment: yes it is 4 years old.